# Overload not working in this instance?

Tags: c++

```
    // How to write a function and use.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


double add(double x, double y)
{
    return x+ y;
}

double add(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}


    int main()
    {
        auto a = add(3, 4);                              // calling the funciton
        cout << "3 + 4 is " << a;                       // printing a out
        double b = add(1.2, 3.4);                       // calling the funciton
        cout << endl;
        cout << "1.2 + 3.4 is " << b;                   // printing a out

        cout << endl;
        double c = add(1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3);
        cout << "1.1 + 2.2 + 3.3 is" << c;

        return 0;
    }
```

Hello everyone, I am trying to do an overload using "add" two times.  For some reason the second time I use add, it is not being recognized as an overload.  I receive an error, no overloaded function takes 1 argument.  The first add works correctly but the second add does not.

Can someone please take a look at explain what I am doing wrong?  I do not see what is wrong with my code?  I am using Visual Studio C++.

Thank you.

Comment: No overloaded function (`add`) takes one argument. You're welcome.

Comment: read a book on how to pass parameters and overload functions instead

Comment: @Durgesh: Please put answers in the answer section.

Comment: @Bathsheba : transferred comment to answer.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is here:

`double c = add(1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3);`

`1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3` is an expression of type `double`.

But you have not specified a version of `add` with a single argument to which a `double` will convert, so the compiler emits an error.

Did you mean `double c = add(1.2, 2.2, 3.3);`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    double c = add(1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3);
```

What are you doing above? Essentially you are passing a single argument to `add` (result of summing 1.2, 2.2 and 3.3). Have you defined `add` with a single argument? No, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

`double c = add(1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3);` should be replaced with `double c = add(1.2, 2.2, 3.3);` as the argument for 1st expression would be addition of 1.2, 2.2, 3.3 and make it to single argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's no version of `add` that takes one double:

```
double c = add(1.2 + 2.2 + 3.3); // they are summed ans passed as one parameter.
```

to overload it then:

```
double add(double a)
{
    return a;
}
```

But there's no logic in a function that summs to values any you declare it with one.